# Delphi: Name of Method that is called for updating content of TxcDateEdit (or TEdit) control needed

Tags: delphi, devexpress

I'm writing a routine which checks the input of an `TcxDateEdit` (from DevExpress). After a number is typed in, it should check it and try to autocomplete the rest of the content. In this case, if the user types in the day in an empty `TcxDateEdit` Control it should automatically fill in the current month and year.

The problem is I need to fire this autocompletion method after the number is typed by the user and visually added in the `TcxDateEdit` Control. So that I can check the actual input. But for this I'm searching for the name of the method which is used by this control to actually update the `TcxDateEdit`. I don't mean a method which implies focus lost, I mean a method which is called by simply typing in the control after (or while) each typed key is added to the String Variable with the content of this control. I'm pretty sure that a similar method exists even in the common TEdit control. So if somebody could tell me the name of this method I would be very thankful.

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: You aren't looking for the `OnChange` event, are you?

Comment: In a standard `TEdit` (well, `TCustomEdit`), that would be the `OnChange` event, which is called by the `Change` method, which is called from `CMTextChanged`, which is caused by the `CM_TEXTCHANGED` message being received. (You can find this information yourself in the `StdCtrls` unit, and should be able to do so in the DevExpress source as well. I'm posting a comment instead of an answer because I don't use DevExpress controls, and therefore don't have access to the source to confirm that the procedures are the same.)

Comment: Surely you can work this out. You do have the source. Also, you would do well to use a control that supports auto complete. The standard windows edit does.

Comment: Maybe you are looking of the OnChange event of the TcxCustomDateEditProperties e.g. `procedure TForm1.cxDateEditPropertiesChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
      Caption := TcxDateEdit(Sender).EditingText; 
end;`

Comment: Hello, sadly there is no `onChange` neither an `cxDateEditPropertiesChange` method in `TcxDateEdit`. The problem is that it is mandatory for me to use this control, because I'm only adding a function in an already existing project. Normally I would just browse through the help files but the help files from devExpress contains only a fraction of the hole functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you ask is possible using the `OnChange` event of the `Properties`, as shown in following image

[image: OnChange event for Properties of TcxDateEdit]

Using this event and the `EditingText` property for your edit, you can use following code:

```
uses DateUtils, StrUtils;

procedure TForm1.cxDateEdit1PropertiesChange(Sender: TObject);
var
  Month : Word;
  Year  : Word;
  Day : Word;
  BarPos : integer;
  DateEdit : TcxDateEdit;
begin
  DateEdit := (Sender as TcxDateEdit);
  BarPos := Pos('/', DateEdit.EditingText);
  if BarPos > 0 then
  begin
    Month := MonthOf(Now);
    Year  := YearOf(Now);
    Day   := StrToInt(LeftStr(DateEdit.EditingText, BarPos -1 ));
    DateEdit.Date := EncodeDate(Year, Month, Day);
  end;
end;
```

This code automatically assigns current Month and Year when Day is typed in by the user, but you can adapt it to whatever are your requirements.

I tested this on Delphi 2006 with version 6.42 of the DevExpress ExpressEditors Library.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now I know that the event is part of the group properties. My Problem was to find the method who called this event, now I could searched directly for the methodname. The needed method is `DoOnChange();` which I have overridden by adding the autocomplete functionality.